# IBindingList And IBindingListView

Tags: c#, list

How can it be?

`List<T>` doesn't implement `IBindingList` / `IBindingListView` - thus it cannot provide UI updates. You are going to need to change a few bits of code to suit the BindigList api.

Comment: Btw, if I wrote "foray", it just means my iPod has lousy spelling auto-correct

Answer (score 2):

UI notifications are done typically via events. This means, in this case, IBindingList and the `ListChanged` event; but also some side interfaces like IBindingListView, and a few other optional things for improved list adding etc. `BindingList<T>` supports pretty much everything you need, but as a consequence has some small overheads.

By contrast, `List<T>` deliberately provides **none** of this; it is a general purpose (and fast) dynamic list device, not an "observer" device.

Note you also typically need your type `T` to implement INotifyPropertyChanged if you want cell-by-cell updates; without this you can only get row-level updates (add, remove,  etc).

For example:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

static class Program
{
    class Foo
    {
        public int A { get; set; }
        public string B { get; set; }
    }
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        using (var form = new Form())
        using (var grid = new DataGridView { Dock = DockStyle.Fill })
        using (var add = new Button { Dock = DockStyle.Bottom, Text = "add" })
        using (var remove = new Button { Dock = DockStyle.Top, Text = "remove" })
        {
            form.Controls.Add(grid);
            form.Controls.Add(add);
            form.Controls.Add(remove);
            var lst = new BindingList<Foo>();
            var rnd = new Random();
            add.Click += delegate
            {
                lst.Add(new Foo { A = rnd.Next(1, 6), B = "new" });
            };
            remove.Click += delegate
            {
                int index = 0;
                foreach (var row in lst)
                { // just to illustrate removing a row by predicate
                    if (row.A == 2) { lst.RemoveAt(index); break; }
                    index++;
                }
            };
            grid.DataSource = lst;
            Application.Run(form);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, if the list is to connect what was dataGridViwe? And after the update(delete, Add ,...) list<T>, dataGridViwe  will also update.

Comment: @mah_85 in that case, bindinglist would raise the events to tell the UI what happened, and the UI will update. `List<T>` exposes no such event, so the UI **cannot** automatically update itself.

Comment: Thank you very much.
Please write the code as windows forms Application.
Thank you

Comment: @mah_85 - that **is** a windows forms application; the `using System.Windows.Forms;` is a bug clue. Any examples here are deliberately minimal for example purposes. But the same approach will work in regualar code.

Comment: Frankly, I'll choose to write examples in the way I feel is most appropriate to the collected audience. The concept this is showing is *alarmingly* simple - just "use a `BindingList<T>`" - and the code in this example is minimal but complete and runnable. If the concept isn't clear from this...

Comment: code Remove for BindingList<T> lst:

    var search = lst.First(s => s.Number == textBox4.Text);
    lst.Remove(search);

    its right?

Comment: @mah_85 that'll work, assuming there is a match. I deliberately avoided LINQ in case it wasn't familiar, but if you're happy to use LINQ: great

Comment: This little example is really brilliant how compact it can be written

Many thanks.